# Installing latest Chromium with version 1

Tags: chromium

I have Raspberry Pi B+ (version 1)

I have been googling and trying tutorials and suggestions for 3 hours or so, and I cannot for the life me get chromium that works with the chrome web store ( I think I need version 32+ of which the default wheezy is version 22)

I upgraded raspbian from wheezy to jessie in hopes that the version 42 (per https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=109309&p=751381) would install, but `apt-get install chromium` or `apt-get install chromium-browser` returns  "has no installation candidate" even though my sources.list has

`deb http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/ jessie main contrib non-free rpi`

It seems the binaries don't exist in the repo?

I don't need raspbian OS, I just need something that can run chrome/chromium and can use extensions (specifically chromecast)

Comment: Have you tried updating your package lists with `sudo apt-get update` before you install?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Short answer**

There is currently no easy way to get a recent Chromium build on the rpib+.

**Options**

If you just want chromecast you could try some [projects](https://github.com/balloob/pychromecast) that don't use Chromium because the rpib+ is RAM limited (limiting Chromium functionality) and has a less popular CPU architecture (limiting your install options).

If you really want a recent version of Chromium you need to find a package compiled for your CPU architecture or build it yourself. Note that Chromium builds often lack a lot of features available in Google Chrome (webRTC, pdf viewing, etc).

It appears the distributions of popular branches of linux available for the rpib+ do not have what you are looking for, but you can check all the options [here](http://elinux.org/RPi_Distributions#Comparison).

**Raspbian/Debian**

Looking at the URL in

```
cat /etc/apt/sources.list
```

You can [see](http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/dists/) that the official OS (raspbian) for the rpi currently has 3 versions:

- debian 7 wheezy
- debian 8 jessie
- debian 9 stretch

apt will tell you where in the repository the files are

```
apt-cache show chromium | grep Filename
```

allowing you to [see](http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/pool/main/c/chromium-browser/) what Chromium versions are available Though it looks like only v22 is available (looks like v42 for the rpi2).

**Pidora/Fedora**

Fedora does not include Chromium in the core repositories and [neither](http://pidora.ca/pidora/releases/20/packages/armv6hl/os/Packages/c/) does Pidora.

**Arch**

Arch Linux ARM [only](http://archlinuxarm.org/packages) has Chromium builds for ARMv7 not ARMv6.

**Raspberry Pi 2**

The Raspberry Pi 2 has a more common CPU architecture (ARMv7) And you can get more recent builds from Ubuntu.

**Build it yourself**

Trying to [build](https://www.chromium.org/developers/how-tos/get-the-code) it yourself will use up all your RAM and crash your raspberrypi (256MB) but this is the method you could use in [qemu](http://wiki.qemu.org/Main_Page) or adapt to cross compile. Also note that chromium may require patches to compile and run on the raspberrypi:

```
mkdir /opt/chromium
cd /opt/chromium
#tmux new -s chromium
git clone --depth 1 https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/tools/depot_tools.git
export PATH=$PATH:/opt/chromium/depot_tools
nice fetch --nohooks --no-history chromium
./build/install-build-deps.sh
gclient runhooks
./build/gyp_chromium -Dcomponent=shared_library -Dfastbuild=1
nice ninja -C out/Release chrome
#echo out/Debug/chrome
```

Comment: I tried `sudo dpkg -i chromium-browser_37.0.2062.120-0ubuntu0.12.04.1~pkg917_armhf.deb` but getting error due to the `libc6.so.6` version. How did you resolve that? THE ERROR: ```dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of chromium-browser:
 chromium-browser depends on libc6 (>= 2.15-0ubuntu8); however:
  Version of libc6:armhf on system is 2.13-38+rpi2+deb7u8.
 chromium-browser depends on chromium-codecs-ffmpeg-extra (>= 0.6) | chromium-codecs-ffmpeg (>= 0.6); however:
  Package chromium-codecs-ffmpeg-extra is not installed.
  Package chromium-codecs-ffmpeg is not installed.
```

Comment: Version 37 requires `libc6 (>= 2.15` and latest Raspbian provides only with `2.13`. I can't see how you could possibly assert that Version 37 for `armhf` you pointed at, only you have a special hack

Comment: @joelmaranhao it's easyer if you just install Ubuntu

Comment: The source code for Chromium is listed here: https://www.chromium.org/developers/how-tos/get-the-code . You can use this to build your own ARMv6 version. Says it's 22GB(!!!!) so make sure you have that kind of space :)