# Can I install Chromium or Iceweasle onto my Pi

Tags: web-browsers, chromium

In the new distro of Raspbian?  I have done searches here but cannot find anything about whether or not I can use Chromium or Iceweasle on Raspbian Jessie. I would like to test browsers and find out which is fastest for my needs.

Running Raspbian Jessie on a Pi2b,  about to upgrade to a pi3b.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can install both though chromium needs a 3rd party binary install or to built from source. To install iceweasel use the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install iceweasel
```

Details on installing chromium can be found [here](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/41611/56), you can also [build from source](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/31267/installing-latest-chromium-with-version-1?rq=1)

Comment: thank you. In your experience,  which is better?  Chromium or Iceweasle? Or are they basically comparable?

Comment: I am not sure there is that much difference, unless you need a specific function or api. If you need support for a specific feature you can check browser support at caniuse.com.

Comment: nope. No special needs. Just looking for faster browsing.

Comment: So I've run into a problem. I used the sudo command to get Iceweasle... But it says that its unable to locate package iceweasle

Comment: @BadgerTrucking check your spelling it is spelled wrong in your comment

Comment: Well... Spelling it correctly helps haha... But now I have another problem. When it asks the if I want to continue,  I press y enter,  and it pops up with "unable to fetch some archives,  maybe run apt-get update or try with - - fix missing?" im not sure what to do from here.

Comment: have you tried what it suggests either sudo apt-get update or sudo apt-get install --fix missing?

Comment: Yes,  and I haven't been able to make any kind of headway. Sudo apt-get update only results in multiple errors popping up. I try "" "install iceweasel" and it shoot out the error message about get update or fix-missing,  and the result is o upgraded 0 newly installed,  o to remove and 2 not upgraded.

Comment: @BadgerTrucking telling us that apt-get update throws an error is not helpful what error message?

Comment: Give me a second and I'll take a picture. I am going to have to post the pictures as answers. I am doing all of this on mobile stack exchange and it won't let me post pictures as a comment.

Comment: Oh my goodness... Technology is weird. So,  sudo apt-get update somehow decided to work. So the update worked... However,  using "install iceweasel"  results in the Pi freezing during the unpacking.